# How to remove index.php from URL in Dokerized Codeigniter 4 application?

Tags: php, docker, .htaccess, apache2, codeigniter-4

I have tried using below two code but still not removed, but 2nd code working very fine in servers and localhost . need solution for removing index.php from url while running application in Dockerized file.
1.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

2. 

```
# Disable directory browsing
Options All -Indexes
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Rewrite engine
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Turning on the rewrite engine is necessary for the following rules and features.
# FollowSymLinks must be enabled for this to work.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteEngine On
    # If you installed CodeIgniter in a subfolder, you will need to
    # change the following line to match the subfolder you need.
    # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase
    # RewriteBase /
    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]
    # Rewrite "www.example.com -> example.com"
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
    # Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
    # such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
    # request to the front controller, index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^([\s\S]*)$ index.php/$1 [L,NC,QSA]
    # Ensure Authorization header is passed along
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
    ErrorDocument 404 index.php
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    <FilesMatch "\.(ttf|ttc|otf|eot|woff|woff2|font.css|css|js)$">
        Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
# Disable server signature start
    ServerSignature Off
# Disable server signature end
```

Comment: Neither of those code blocks actually "remove index.php from the URL". They allow URLs that do not contain `index.php` to be routed through `index.php` (the "front-controller"). Apart from the additional directives, both #1 and #2 are the same in this respect. Have you enabled `.htaccess` overrides? Is mod_rewrite installed?

Comment: yes .htaccess overrides have enabled but still not working in dockerized file .